# Binary logit with time series

Tags: regression, time-series, logistic

I intend to run a Binary Logit with Wholesale Price Index of different commodities. I have converted these scale variables into categorical variables with the following criterion:

1=Price has increased when compared to previous period
0=Price has remained stable or decreased in comparison to previous period

With the above criterion, all predictors have been converted into categorical variables. Could I then estimate using the usual Binary Logit option in SPSS or should I still make some correction to the data or adopt a different procedure? My aim is to study the inter-dynamics between sectors ... Eg:  With increase in the price of iron, the odds that there would be an increase in the price of Cement.

I would be grateful if anyone could guide me in this regard.